# Can't Build or publish App maui with a lot of errors

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.android, maui

My app works fine on IOS and Android on startup, however when I try to publish the app on Android I get all these errors :

```
android app .net maui 1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4911,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Users\0infi\.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.core\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h" to "bin\Release\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Release\net7.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.Core.resources\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\GoogleUtilitiesComponents.framework\Headers\GoogleUtilitiesComponents-umbrella.h'. 

etc
```

[image]

[image]

I tried clean, delete bin and obj file, build, rebuild

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the error message indicating that the package `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core` cannot be built on the Android platform. You can check the the [framework of the Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core/#supportedframeworks-body-tab) to see it is the package for the IOS platform.

Comment: But actually I don't have this package...

Comment: You can check the NuGet package folder to find if it is in the folder and then you can delete it.

Comment: I found the firebases files in the bin that I deleted but that doesn't change anything, is there another folder you mean?

Comment: you might do not delete the package `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core` in the project file folder, and you can check the folder in the error you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is often also happening because of exceeding MAX_PATH (260 characters size) of file which is tried to be found. But if mentioned approach do not work try this:

Close all visual studio instances.

Run PowerShell as Administrator and execute this command

**New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabl ed" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force**

Create a new folder with name "Nugets" in drive C ( C:\Nugets )

Again run PowerShell as Administrator and execute following command:

**[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NUGET_PACKAGES", "C:\Nugets" ,"Machine")**

Delete obj and bin folder of your project

Run Visual Studio and Rebuild Project

7.0 DID not worked yet ?

7.1 Close Visual Studio

7.2 Open CMD/PowerShell and navigate to the folder of your project e.g.: **cd "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\MySolution\MyProject"** and than run command **dotnet restore**

7.3 Open Visual Studio again and build

Answer (score 0):

This changes in the Business and Domain class libraries: net7.0 --> by
net7.0;net7.0-maccatalyst;net7.0-android;net7.0-ios